# How are "i.e." and "e.g." pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations, latin, initialisms

How are [*i.e.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/i.e.) and [*e.g.*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/e.g.) pronounced?

Comment: Why do English use Latin abbreviations anyway?

In norwegian we use "dvs." as short for "det vil si" ("that is"), and
"f.eks." as short for "for eksempel" ("for example"), and we would never pronounce it as an abbrevation (unless you're trying to sound geeky).

Comment: @Stein: In English, it's used to sound smart.

Comment: @Stein -- Latin abbreviations are a holdover from the period where Latin was a standard part of the curriculum. I.e., e.g, and even etc. were common abbreviation used by scholars for centuries. We still invent and use abbreviations. Now we have lol and wtf.

Comment: @Jay: Then, how to pronounce `lol`? `loll` or `laugh out loud`? The latter seems very prolix.

Comment: As an exception, *etc* is pronounced *et cetera*.

Comment: @XièJìléi: If you're making fun of the person who used "lol", you pronounce it "lawl".

Comment: Interesting, if this question was asked today it would be closed as general reference and would get a dozen downvotes. The ELU community has become a lot more haughty and aggressive

Comment: This question has been answered, there can be no other alternative answer, there is no scope for detailed thoughtful discussion. Please close this question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, with all due respect, that a Stack Exchange 'question has been answered, [and] there can be no other alternative answer' is not generally regarded as a reason for closing it. If it were, thousands of questions that are currently open would need to be closed, and this site would considerably change its character. If the worry is that the question may invite frivolous answers from one-time visitors, it is always possible to 'protect' it, while leaving it otherwise open.

Comment: @jsw29 Not every question is the same. Not every question has the one single answer because as far as I can tell nearly all the answers say "eye-ee" and "ee-gee". This was posted in **2010**, today it would be closed and deleted within days. How many acceptable ways are there to ***pronounce*** "i.e" and "e.g"? I'm all ears. P.S All the answers were posted in the same year, no one in over ten years looked at it and thought, I could write a better answer.

Comment: Closing a question and deleting it are two very different things, please don't confuse the two. A closed question remains visible, and shows visitors that EL&U has since evolved. This question, despite its views and upvotes, today would be off-topic but not on ELL.

Comment: @endolith You say that, but I see people mess up _i.e._ and _e.g._ more often than not, making them seem all the less smart.  ;-)

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug comparing the closure of a simple English language question on SE to that of the Nazis and Fascists parties is incredibly insulting to all those people who were killed during their reign of power. How anyone compare the two is beyond me.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug Yes, that's the point.  Like "thusly", it's used to sound smarter than you actually are.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

**i.e.** stands for *id est* (Latin), which means "*that is*". You use it to link in a deeper explanation about something.
Pronounce it "eye - ee".

**e.g.** stands for *exempli gratia* (also Latin), which means "*for example*". You use it to link in an example of a more generic term.
Pronounce it "ee - jee"

Comment: Can I read them out as, 'that is' and 'for example'? (When there's some audience)

Comment: It depends on who your audience is. Children, I think, would be distracted with the abbreviations. Educated adults wouldn't mind, though.

Comment: I have lived my entire adult life thinking "i.e." stood for "in essence". Thanks for this!

Comment: @Ray: I always read them aloud as such, and it can get amusing when reading the work of others who have used them incorrectly. Oh, if only I had the chance to read more bad literature aloud...

Comment: @Paul I have a friend who thought *e.g.* stood for “example given.” At least the mnemonic would prevent inappropriate substitution of *i.e.*

Comment: exempli gratia does not mean "for example", it means "free example", which is essentially the same thing.

Comment: You are not supposed to pronounce these as read-out letters; you are supposed to pronounce them as their English equivalents.

Comment: @Malfist EXEMPLI GRATIA does not mean _free example_, it means "for the sake of an example". One shouldn't mistake the Latin noun grātia (_grace, thankfulness, sake,_ present only in Romance languages) for the Latin adjective gratis (_free_, present both in the Romance and the Germanic languages).

Comment: I always pronounce them, along with `etc.` in the fully Roman, maximum show-off way when possible.

Comment: a bridge word between 'free' and 'grace' might be 'favor'

Comment: @SimonKuang So [ekˡsempliː ˡɡɾaːtiʲaː] and [et ˡketeɾa]? I suspect most English speakers wouldn't even understand what you meant. Do you also pronounce _§_ as [ˡskiːliket] or [ˡsiŋna sektiʲoːnis], depending on meaning?

Answer (score 127):

For `i.e.` I usually say "that is", occasionally "eye-ee".

For `e.g.` I always say "for example".

Comment: Can `e.g.` be pronounced as *'ack'*?

Comment: Sure, but that'd make you weird.

Answer (score 56):

When I was in college, one of my philosophy professors instructed us to use translated English for abbreviated or initialized latinisms when reading a text aloud.  I would agree that in most cases you should speak the translated English rather than speaking the letters of the initialization.

- *i.e.* is used for clarification and should be spoken *"that is"*.  While most English speakers will recognize the meaning of *"eye ee"* when spoken, saying *"that is"* is clearer.
- *e.g.* is used for providing one or many examples and should be spoken *"for example"*.

While *i.e.* and *e.g.* are relatively common, other abbreviated or initialized latinisms, such as *viz.*, are less frequent and their English translation should certainly be provided when reading from a text that includes a latinism.

For example, take the following [quote from Plato](http://www.quotesea.com/quote/perfectwisdomhasfourpartsvizwisdomthe):

> Perfect wisdom has four parts, viz., wisdom, the principle of doing things aright; justice, the principle of doing things equally in public and private; fortitude, the principle of not flying danger, but meeting it; and temperance, the principle of subduing desires and living moderately.

When reading that quote aloud, the translation for *viz.* should be provided.

- Incorrect:

  - "Perfect wisdom has four parts, ***viz***, wisdom, the principle..."
  - "Perfect wisdom has four parts, ***videlicet***, wisdom, the principle..."
- Correct:

  - "Perfect wisdom has four parts, ***namely***, wisdom, the principle..."
  - "Perfect wisdom has four parts, ***that is to say***, wisdom, the principle..."

Speaking the translation for initialized and abbreviated latinisms provides greater clarity for the audience than simply speaking the initials or the latin.

Comment: Plato was Greek and lived at a time when the Romans had little (if any) influence on Greek language or culture. I wonder how he came to use the abbreviation "viz." :-)

Comment: +1 But how will blowhards satisfy their pomposity needs without liberal seasoning with vocalized latinisms?

Comment: @Greg, remember "Quidquid latine dictum sit, altum viditur," which translates into "Whatever is said in Latin sounds profound."

Comment: This is the correct answer: you pronounce them as their English equivalents.

Comment: +1, I have been pronouncing 'viz' as 'viz'. 'namely' is appropriate. Thanks for sharing the correct usage.

Comment: @AndrewNeely It doesn't. It doesn't translate into anything, because _viditur_ is not a word. _Quidquid latine dictum sit altum videtur_, on the other hand, translates into “Anything which is said in Latin appears deep”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I bow to your greater knowledge.

Answer (score 24):

Just pronounce the letters: "Eye eee" and "eee gee".

I have never met anyone who actually said "id est" and "exempli gratia", which is what they really stand for.

Comment: Did you meant "eee jee" and not "eee gee"?

Comment: @Ismail: They're pronounced the same, and "gee" is even an English word (http://merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gee). Either will do.

Comment: Shouldn't "Eye eee" be written "Eye ee"?

Answer (score 11):

I can't believe this wasn't addressed in the [Oatmeal Comic](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/ie) but I usually say the letters or replace it with "for example" (and now, thanks to the comic, I'll replace it with "in other words" instead and use e.g. when I mean "for example").

Answer (score 9):

and as for the pronunciation of the Latin:

**i.e. = id est



e.g. = 
IgzemplI gra:tI**

(NB a: is pronounced like the "a" in car or can't)

but remember - as has been mentioned here; it's much better practice to use the English long-forms in speech:

i.e. - "that is" / "or"
e.g. - "for example"

Comment: What happened to the "a" at the end of "gratia"? Is it not pronounced? (I'm a beginner to Latin, especially pronunciation which I haven't been paying much attention to…)

Comment: A more modern an common (British) pronunciation would be {gra:tI}  However classical Latin would retain the "a:" sound at the end - {gra:tIa:}

Comment: Which pronunciation are you trying to indicate here? a) reconstructed Latin pronunciation b) restored pronunciation of Latin for English speakers c) traditional English pronunciation of Latin? As it is, your indicated pronunciations are an inconsistent hybrid of b and c (you indicate a voiced /gz/ rather than /ks/ for the "x", but a broad /a:/ for "a" and monophthongal /I/ for "i").

Comment: @herisson, good points.  And is the first _e_ in _exempli_ really pronounced /I/?  Only asking because I've never heard any civilized Latin-based language speakers pronounce an _e_ like that.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug: You probably wouldn't have heard it: English speakers rarely have occasion to pronounce *exempli gratia* as part of an English sentence. But just as English speakers often pronounce /I/ in the first syllable of *example* and *exemplary,* it would also be typical in an English pronunciation of Latin (the type of pronunciation whereby "stare decisis" rhymes with "vary the crisis") to use /ɪ/ in the first syllable of *exempli gratia.*

Answer (score 9):

Latin abbreviations

1. i.e. = that is, such as, or "in other words"
2. e.g = for example
3. et. al. = and others (i get a lot of strange looks when I use this)
4. NB. = nota bene; Note well (and this one as well... I have no idea why this one is capitalized)
5. etc. = et cetera ("and other things", or "and so forth")

and yes when reading aloud I just use the translation to avoid confusion

Pronuciation: just say the letters for most cases; except etc. and et cetera are pronounced the same.

et. al. is pronounced et all

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about pronunciation.

Comment: @EleventhDoctor: I updated my answer...