# About i.e. and e.g

Tags: word-usage, terminology, pronunciation, abbreviations, latin

I have four small questions about i.e. and e.g.

1. How do you call them, “words” or other things?
2. When using (writing or typing), do we usually use the italic version *i.e.* / *e.g.* or the normal version i.e. and e.g.
3. when using them, do we usually add a “,” after them?
4. How do you pronounce them.

Thanks!

Comment: It is common to speak "that is" for "i.e." and "for example" for "e.g.".

Comment: Number 4 is a [Duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118525/2085).

Answer (score 3):

They are *abbreviations* for the Latin *exempli gratia* (for example) and *id est* (that is). The choice of italic (to indicate Latin) or not is arbitrary, according to the publication; whichever is used, care should be taken that the same form is used consistently throughout the publication. The comma is not necessary and could be confusing coming immediately after a fullstop. I suggest that it is helpful to regard the full stop in abbreviations as standing for any *missing* letters (e.g. D. Smith instead of David Smith, but Dr Smith for Doctor Smith). I have always heard them pronounced as *eee geee* and *I eee*, as in normal letters of the alphabet. I hope this helps.

Comment: When using them (always in writing -- they're never spoken unless someone is reading aloud verbatim), I usually use a comma at the end instead of a period. I.e, like this. There's no need for periods at all except to identify the abbreviation, and one period will do that; the comma is for what is to follow.

Comment: @John You may move in a higher linguistic register than I. I often hear (and wince at) presentations in which people say e g or, less often, i e.The question asked for pronunciation; I gave it; that does not mean I like to hear it.

Comment: Thank you. It’s very detailed!