# How is "viz." pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, latin

How does one read out “*viz.*”? “Namely”, “to wit”, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/577/95822), the correct approach is to translate as you vocalize, so you would say "namely" instead of pronouncing it as "*viz*".  However, I have never (knowingly) heard anyone do this, and would probably simply pronounce it as "*viz*" myself.

Also, anyone who knows of [Viz Comic](http://www.viz.co.uk) (warning, not entirely suitable for work) - which essentially means anyone who was in their teens or twenties and living in the UK since the 1980s - will enjoy the associations brought back by hearing the word.

Answer (score 1):

For "viz." you are supposed to say "namely," but could also say "videlicet" (pronounced wih-deh-lih-ket).