# How would you pronounce N.B. (nota bene) when reading aloud?

Tags: pronunciation

I know how to pronounce nota bene ([YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIZ1YTnm9TY) can help if your Italian is rusty), but if you were reading an academic paper aloud (or something else that would contain *notate bene*), how would you go about saying "N.B." before continuing to read the note? Simply "note", or the proper "nota bene"?

Comment: I would say *N.B.*

Comment: Either _Note:_ or _En Bee:_.

Comment: N.B.: _Nota bene_ is Latin, not Italian (though it would happen to be the same in Italian here).

Comment: Do whatever you would do if you were saying "i.e." or "e.g." instead.  Since that's the way it's written, most people would just pronounce the letters.  Someone really pretentious would probably say "id est" or "exempli gratia".  I myself, being a pedant, tend to just sneakily translate it to "that is" or "for example".

Comment: When I come across "e.g." when I'm reading some text aloud to people, I not only say "exempli gratia," I pause to ask whether they know the cases of the two words, and then I sneer at anyone who doesn't know.  What do you say when you read "etc."?  I hate it when people say "etsy."

Comment: Ppl who pronounce br8shnz also say ee tee cee.

Comment: @deadrat This is excellent. But _etc._ is typically written as if it's an abbreviation of a single word, so I think most English speakers probably say "et seterah" (or "ex eterah," which I hear all the time).  If it were written like a typical Latin->English abbreviation it would be "e.c.."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pronounce  *N.B.* (also written as *NB* or n.b., nb)  as

/ˌenˈbiː/.

([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/nb)). See also [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/nb). In other words you say the names of the two letters, just like for *e.g.* (also *eg*) ( /ˌiː ˈdʒiː/). ([MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/e-g?q=e.g.)) You can also say *Note* or *Note well*, which  parallels saying *for example* for *e.g.*

NB that the  *NB* is from the Latin  *nota bene* although the phrase is the same  in Italian.

See also [How are "i.e." and "e.g." pronounced?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574/how-are-i-e-and-e-g-pronounced)

Comment: None of your references address reading aloud. FWIW, I would read *e.g.* aloud as "for example".

Comment: @michael.hor257k then vote to close the question as opinion-based

Comment: Non sequitur...

Comment: In addition, the answer states that one can read out *e.g.* as *for example*.

Comment: @michael.hor257k You might also want to compare [your answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/363548/210913) to *How is 'et al 'pronounced?*, which is rather draconian and gives no reference to back it up.

Comment: I am well aware of my answer. I am afraid your missing the point of my original comment: the references that you cite do not support your assertion. That part of your answer is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

According to Cambridge English Pronouncing dictionary, it's:

> BrE - ˌnəʊtɑːˈbeneɪ, -təˈbiːnɪ, US -  ˌnoʊt̬əˈbeneɪ, - tɑːˈ-, -ˈbiːni

Comment: Is that the entry for _NB_, though, or the one for _nota bene_ (if they are distinct)? [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nb) give /ˌenˈbiː/ as the pronunciation of _NB_ (and doesn’t have an entry for _nota bene_ at all).

Comment: Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary by Daniel Jones

Comment: That wasn’t what I asked… and you haven’t actually answered the question here at all. The asker states that he knows how to pronounce the words _nota bene_. He’s asking how you would read the abbreviation “N.B.” in a document out loud—whether you’d read it out as the words _nota bene_ or in some other way. Giving the pronunciation to the words _nota bene_ does not answer that question.

Comment: THAT is how i'd read it out loud

Comment: Your answer should say so, then—preferably with some kind of source to make it more than just “this is what I would do”.

Comment: you're free to edit any time you want

Comment: As are you. It’s your answer and your responsibility to make it a good one. As it is, it’s not.

Comment: this is a ludicrous comment i know that actually looking at the way the question is formulated you may understand that it's pretty much "opinion-based" and should be closed consider that for a second

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, it's all our responsibility to ensure good answers.  I edit answers all the time to make them more clear and to fix typos.  If you think this site is "my way or highway," then you'd make a good dev or mod here as they don't care about us "users," but (most of) the rest of us here actually care about the community and about working together to create good answers.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug I too edit answers to improve them all the time. That doesn’t mean answerers are not responsible for their own answers. Substantially editing an answer that doesn’t address the question in order to turn it into one that does, and thereby potentially going against the answerers intentions, is not what the edit function is intended for. (Also, this answer is more than seven years old.)