# How is 'et al 'pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

As we know the term 'et al 'is used frequently to denote a team along with a specific person,how is it actually pronounced?

For eg.Sir William Brown et al have conducted extensive studies on black holes.

I have heard the pronunciation as 'et al' itself and usages like 'and others'.How should it be correctly pronounced?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? You can find audio [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/pronunciation/english/et-al).

Comment: Whatever the many 'proper' suggestions, translating to English, the full Latin, et cetera and so on, I've only ever heard or said /ɛt æl/.

Comment: I've never heard it pronounced as anything other than "et all" as if the "al" was the word "all"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to pronouce 'et al.' is given in many dictionaries. For instance [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/et-al).

If you are asking whether you should actually say 'et al.' or something different, that is up to you. Academia has a close question: ['et al' in presentation speech](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/61951/et-al-in-presentation-speech), and the remarks there suggest 'and others', 'and coauthors', and the accepted answer suggests 'and his/her group/coauthors/colleagues'.

You could say: "Sir William Brown and (his) coauthors'. However, you can just say "Sir William Brown et al."

Comment: Welcome to the site @Claire!

Answer (score 2):

"*et al.*" is an abbreviation. When read aloud, you pronounce the full term "*et alii*" (or "*et alia*")  - same as you would say "*et cetera*" when reading aloud the "*etc.*" abbreviation.

Alternatively, you could say "*and others*" - same as you would say "*for example*" when reading aloud the "*e.g.*" abbreviation.

Comment: This answer contains no reference. I read aloud *et al.* as *et all*.

Comment: In England, you will occasionally hear speakers pronounce ‘i.e.’ and ‘e.g.’ as the names of those alphabetical letters.  E.g. “aye ee” and “ee gee”.  Indeed, I'll do it occasionally, but I rarely use those except in written form.

Comment: One correction: *et alii* is the correct form for human beings. *Et alia* is neuter plural, which is never used for citations... unless robots or abstract energy beings coauthored the paper.

Answer (score 0):

If you must pronounce it, it is quite straightforward: ‘et’ as in ‘etiquette’, ‘al’ as in ‘Alexander’.

But I always discouraged my students from speaking Latin, and suggested they said “and coworkers” instead. In the context of quoting a paper, then “and co-authors”, as @JanusBahsJacquet suggested, would be better.

Comment: Saying “and coworkers” is probably not a very good idea, since co-authors and co-editors of a volume (or article) are frequently _not_ coworkers.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet — In the specific context of citing a paper — which is what the question was about — I agree. I think the context of my recollections was student seminars, where the reference was more to work from a particular lab.